# How to use of PagingBar (GWTLib)

Tags: gwt

How to use [`PagingBar`](http://code.google.com/p/gwtlib/wiki/PagingBar) widget in [gwtlib](http://code.google.com/p/gwtlib)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GwtExt or smartGWT which has in built local and remote paging and also many different other functionalities and components.

Click [here](http://www.gwt-ext.com/demo/#localPagingGrid) to find out local Pagingtoolbar in Gwtext and you can also find RemotePaging Toolbar there.